# Dictionary derived type as non-navigation property in efcore6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to move one of our projects from efcore5 to efcore6. We have a type that's derived from `Dictionary` as follows.

```cs
public class LinkRelations : Dictionary<string, LinkRelation>
```

where `LinkRelation` is simply;

```cs
public class LinkRelation
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Our ef entity `Notification` has `LinkRelations` as;

```cs
public class Notification
{
    public LinkRelations Links { get; private set; }

    // other stuff
}
```

We configure the `Notification` entity for EF as follows;

```cs
public class NotificationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Notification>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Notification> builder)
    {            
        builder.Property(n => n.Links).HasConversion(new JsonValueConverter<LinkRelations>());     
    }
}

public class JsonValueConverter<T> : ValueConverter<T, string>
{
    public JsonValueConverter() : base(
        v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
        s => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(s))
    {
    }
}
```

When I try to create a new migration (to test), I get the error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Links' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Notification' because it is configured as a navigation.` at the `NotificationConfiguration.Configure` call above.

However, we are actually storing `Links` as a json string. Since, `LinkRelations` is derived from `Dictionary`, I believe EFCore6 is concluding that it must be a navigation property and then falling over.

So, my question is, how can I configure `ef-core-6` to **not** make my property a navigation property? Or any other suggestion to avoid this error?

PS: This is an existing system in prod, and I cannot really modify the current design / schema.

Comment: Quick fix, add `[NotMapped]` to avoid conventions before you have a chance to use the fluent api.

Comment: So, `[NotMapped]` will only reset conventions applied to mapping, and any convention I add via fulent api will be applied and the field will still end up in db fine. If so, please add your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it as an answer as soon as I verify @JeremyLakeman.

Comment: There may be a better answer in EF Core 7, but I haven't read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns yet.

Comment: Yep, saw that too (efcore7 json columns) and excited about it. However, we are still one iteration (of upgrades) behind that :) .